# Amazon EC2 and Elastic Bean

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have developed an application using Amazon Java web project from eclipse console, If I try to publish the project, its not publishing and showing error like [this](http://postimg.org/image/e9ah5cp5t/) and [this](http://postimg.org/image/ufjvgic1t/). Is only possibility to create a web project in Amazon services is through Elastic Beanstalk or else we can create a web project of our own and can be uploaded normally with EC2 instance???. If the question is foolish, please forgive. Am a newbie to Amazon services.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Beanstalk is a managed option. But you can deploy your application on to your own instances.

Comment: That is I dont want to create a web application using beans talk and I can create a dynamic web project in eclipse and an instance in amazon EC2 and publish the code online. Is it so?